# Java API for splitting RDF files

Tags: java, api, split, bigdata, rdf

I would like to use a Java API to split RDF files in java. (not by OS commands).

Does anyone knows any Java library for doing that? Any experience?

I already searched google a lot, but I could not find anything.

Thankyou in advance.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "split"? Do you want to manipulate RDF files?

Comment: Hi, spliting large RDF files and load and evaluate them simultaneously. what do you think about it?

Comment: Are you looking for a parser able to work in parallel to improve treatment speed?

Comment: Yes, to parse and evaluate a big RDF file at the same time and efficiently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Splitting via Parsing

If you are happy to use [Apache Jena](http://jena.apache.org) then you can make use of the [StreamRDF](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/io/streaming-io.html) abstraction.  You can implement a custom `StreamRDF` instance in combination with using the built in [`StreamRDFWriter.getWriterStream()`](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/riot/system/StreamRDFWriter.html) to split up the parsed triples into separate output files.

If you prefer to use [Sesame](http://rdf4j.org) you can use their [RIO](http://rdf4j.org/doc/4/programming.docbook?view#Parsing_and_Writing_RDF_with_Rio) abstraction to achieve something very similar.

#### Splitting without Parsing

Splitting without parsing is **only** possible if using a line based RDF serialisation like NTriples or NQuads, otherwise you will have to parse and split the files that way as there is no safe reliable way to split other serialisations.

If you do have NTriples or NQuads then you can naively split with the *nix `split` command like so:

```
> split -l 50000 input.nq prefix-
```

Where `-l` specifies the number of lines to place into each file, `input.nq` is your input file and `prefix-` is the prefix for the output filenames.  This will produce a bunch of files in the current directory named `prefix-aa`, `prefix-ab` etc depending on how many lines are in your input file.

#### Splitting and Blank Nodes

If your data contains blank nodes then you need to be careful when attempting to split data.

Note that all RDF serialisations are defined such that blank node identifiers in the data are document scoped i.e. they are scoped to the file they appear in.  Thus if you split a file containing blank nodes into multiple files you change the meaning of your data.  This applies whether your split via

For example say you have `_:a` throughout your original file which would be treated as a single blank node.  If you split your file into `N` parts you now have up to `N` different `_:a` across your files each of which is treated as a separate blank node (due to the document scoping) and thus the meaning of your data has been changed because a single node may now be interpreted as `N` different nodes.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I do not want to parse them. I only want to split them.